# location of variable changing?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, c99

I have some code, but for some reason the location of a variable changes in the middle of my code.
In my main I read one integer from stdin, then malloc an array of structs.

```
int main(){
    int numcities;
    scanf("%d", &numcities);

    City **cities = malloc(numcities*sizeof(City)*2); //*2 is just to be sure, gonna remove that later.

    for(int n = 0;n<numcities;n++){
        int nularr[numcities];
        for(int n2 = 0;n2<numcities;n2++){
            nularr[n2] = 0;
        }
        City c = {
            .value = 1,
            .options = nularr,
        };
        cities[n] = &c;
    };

    readRoads(cities, numcities);
}
```

readRoads is shown below. before calling readRoads I can access numcities (gdb and inside the code), but after it sigsegvs when trying to use it, and in gdb complains about not being able to read memory at 0xffffffcd.
If I take a pointer to numcities and dereference it later, everything is intact. but getting the pointer after calling readRoads gives me 0xffffffcd (consistently) which is unreadable.
I already receive twice as much memory from malloc as necessary,

```
void readRoads(City **cities, int N){
    for(int n = 0;n<N;n++){
        int buf;
        int res[N];
        int roads = 0;
        City *options[N];
        scanf("%d", &buf);
        for(int r = 0;r<N;r++){
            res[r]= buf << r;
            if(res[r]){
                options[roads] = cities[r];
                roads++;
            }
        }

        cities[n]->id = n;
        cities[n]->name = n +'A';
        cities[n]->optionsCount = 1;

        for(int i = 0; i < roads; i++){
            cities[n]->options[i] = options[i]->id;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you assign to the `cities` array:

```
for(int n = 0;n<numcities;n++){
    int nularr[numcities];
    for(int n2 = 0;n2<numcities;n2++){
        nularr[n2] = 0;
    }
    City c = {
        .value = 1,
        .options = nularr,
    };
    cities[n] = &c;
};
```

You're assigning the address of a local variable.  This variable goes out of scope at the end of the `for` loop, so you end up pointing to invalid memory.  Dereferencing this invalid pointer invokes [undefined behaivor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  The same thing happens when you assign `nularr` to one of these instances

Rather than create an array of pointers to `City`, just create an array of `City`.  Also, you'll need to dynamically allocate `nularr`.

```
City *cities = malloc(numcities*sizeof(City));

for(int n = 0;n<numcities;n++){
    int *nularr = calloc(numcities, sizeof(int);
    cities[n].value = 1;
    cities[n].options = nularr;
};
```

Also change `readRoads` accordingly:

```
void readRoads(City *cities, int N){
    ...
```

And be sure to check the return value of `malloc` / `calloc` for errors.

Comment: Thanks!, coming from golang its all a bit confusing at times. its very logical, just all the little things I never thought about.

Answer (score 0):

```
    City c = {
        .value = 1,
        .options = nularr,
    };
    cities[n] = &c;
}
```

At this `}`, `c` goes out of scope and stops existing (it's a local variable in that block).

The pointer you just saved (`cities[n]`) has become indeterminate.

Basically, cities is now an array of invalid pointers.

---

(Also, it should be initialized as

```
City **cities = malloc(numcities * sizeof (City *));
```

Specifically, `sizeof (City *)`, not `sizeof (City)`.)